# How to do conditionals operations in columns in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make a code that calculates the variation of "prod"("rgdpna"/"emp") in relation to one specific year. In an excel data, that contain data from several countries, and I need to do it **for all of them**.

(country, year, rgdpna and emp, are the data from excel)

```
Contry  year  rgdpna   emp   "prod"(rgdpna/emp)   "prodvar"
Brazil  1980   100     12          8.3           (8.3/8.3) = 1
Brazil  1981   120     12          10            (10/8.3) = 1.2
Brazil  1982   140     15          9.3           (9.3/8.3) = 1.1
...
Canada  1980   300     11          27.2          (27.2/27.2) =  1
Canada  1981   327     10          32.7          (32.7/27.2) = 1.2
Canada  1982   500     12          41.6          (41.6/27.2) = 1.5
...
```

Something like this : "prodvar" = ("prod" when "year" >= 1980) divided by ("prod" when "year"==1980)

And i think i need to do with "while", but i don't know.

```
df["prod"] = df["rgdpna"].div (df["emp"])
```

Comment: Please check how to make a  [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example),so we can help you. What would be your expected output ?

Comment: I edited your question to change the commas to decimal dots. Please, in the future, post your data example as it is in the language that you're using: using the wrong syntax in the middle of a code block is very, very confusing.

Comment: _but i don't know._ That's far too vague, Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pandas, avoid doing for and while loops wherever possible.

Try this.

```
df['prod'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['prod']/df['prod'].loc[(df['year']==1980)&(df['country']==x['country'])].values[0], axis=1)
```

Comment: No problem. Generally speaking beyond the specific answer I gave, you want to use the "apply" function. It's one of your best friends in pandas, especially because there are other libraries that can make it run faster if you need the boost. It will almost always get the job done in a timely manner, in my experience. 

If you want the column conditional on one other column, use apply on that column:
```
df['new_col'] = df['old_col'].apply()
```

For more than one column, use the apply function on the df itself and specify axis=1

Comment: ... was the comment directed to me? I used `.apply` in my answer.

Comment: Oh, I apologize, I got the usernames confused and thought you were the original poster.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's get your data into a complete, minimal example. For that we don't need the intermediate columns, so let's keep the relevant column only, and call it 'value' for clearness' sake:

```
data_dict = {'country': {0: 'Brazil',
  1: 'Brazil',
  2: 'Brazil',
  3: 'Canada',
  4: 'Canada',
  5: 'Canada'},
 'value': {0: 8.3, 1: 10, 2: 9.3, 3: 27.2, 4: 32.7, 5: 41.6},
 'year': {0: 1980.0, 1: 1981.0, 2: 1982.0, 3: 1980.0, 4: 1981.0, 5: 1982.0}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
```

(I'm also using clear column names in the rest of this answer, even if they're long)

Secondly, we will create an intermediate values column, that just holds the value when year is 1980:

```
df['value_1980'] = df.apply(lambda row: df.set_index(['year','country']).loc[1980]['value'][row['country']], axis=1)
```

Finally, we just divide the two, as in your example:

```
df['value_relative_to_1980'] = df['value'] / df['value_1980']
```

Check the result.